# How to design SQL tables to allow for multiple parent table options?

Tags: sql, database-design

Looking into creating a series of tables in a reporting hierarchy and am more or less drawing a blank.

While tables in this structure can only have one parent, how do I structure the fields so that they point to the right parent table?  As you'll see in my example below, a row's parent table can differ.

```
                  ARRANGEMENT
                  /           \
           MATTERS            ISSUES 
              |                     |
            PHASES                MATTERS
          /       \                 |
     ISSUES      TASKS            PHASES
     /    \        |             /      \
 TITLES  TASKS   ISSUES       TASKS    TITLE  
           |        |           |
        TITLES   TITLES       TITLE
```

Essentially, is it best to have each "branch" have a unique table (even though Tasks in branch 1 has the same data structure as branch 2 or 3), or is it best to have the records identify which table is their parent?

```
Arrangement(ID)
Matters(ParentTable, ParentID, ID)
Phases(ParentTable, ParentID, ID)
Issues(ParentTable,ParentID, ID)
Titles(ParentTable,ParentID, ID)
Tasks(ParentTable,ParentID, ID)
```

The above doesn't seem right to me at all.  Help?

Answer (score 4):

I have two opinions.  You must be clear on the meaning of these "polymorphic" entities.  Are they semantically different and separate?  Even if they look the same, you may not want to put them into the same table if they serve different purposes.

---

If a Matter is truly, semantically fungible between Arrangements and Issues, then I'd suggest using a form of "Mapping" tables:

```
Arrangement(ID)
Matters(ID)
Issues(ID)
ArragementMatters (FK_ArrangementID, FK_MatterID)
IssueMatters (FK_IssueID, FK_MatterID)
```

You can continue this pattern throughout the "polymorphic" tables.

You can add a unique constraint on FK_MatterID columns if required.

It's easy to write queries:

```
Select * from Arrangement a 
inner join ArrangementMatters am on am.FK_arrangementID = a.ID
inner join Matters m on m.ID = am.FK_matterID
```

to get all your Matters associated with Arrangements.

---

On the other hand, if a Matter under and Arrangement is NOT semantically fungible and only has the same schema, then I'd suggest creating completely separate tables:

```
Arrangement(ID)
ArrangementMatters(ID, FK_ArrangementID)
Issues(ID)
IssueMatters(ID, FK_IssueID)
```

This conveys the distinction to the world.  It gives you a lot of benefits if you can separate your concerns.  (i.e. Maybe you have lots of heavy usage of IssueMatters vs. ArrangementMatters - you can optimize the indexes and table layout independently.)

A query is also simpler:

```
Select * from Arrangement a 
inner join Matters m on m.FK_arrangementID = a.ID
```

Comment: Jeff,

First off, thanks for your response.  After thinking about it for a bit, I don't think they're semantically fungible.  The ultiamte application is budgeting.  If a task, for example, was a grandparent of an "issue," the task would require a dollar budgeted amount for each task.  However, if the task  were a child of a phase, the _issue_ would require the budget amount, and the task wouldn't (since it's job would be to point tasks to the correct issue management structure).

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that - at least not in any RDBMS I know of, if you use referential integrity (foreign key relationships), since those always have to reference one and exactly one parent table - you cannot have a FK relationship that reference parent table A in one case and parent table B in another.

In your concrete case, where a "Title" could be child of both "Phases" or "Tasks", one way to solve this would be to have a "dummy" Task for those "Title" entries that should be direct children of the "Phases" table.

Anything else will be a hack and a nightmare to maintain in the long run.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

I have seen polymorphic associations of various sorts (not just parent relationships) handled that way in relational databases.  I'd say go ahead and use the `ParentTable, ParentID' approach.

The downsides are that you won't be able to enforce referential integrity at the database level (ie, use foreign keys), and it's going to be a little more work to fetch association unless you're using a framework that will do the legwork for you (eg, Rails).  If you really need polymorphic associations, though, I don't know any good way around those complications.

Comment: Well, it's really going to be a pure SQL framework, so all legwork will be mine.  The real downside (besides the referential integrity issue) I see to this approach would be the SQL statement you'd need to construct to access the data would be grotesque.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 1 table with ID & ParentID.
The top level row (Arrangement) will have NULL ParentID.

Comment: That doesn't really help me know which table the parentid is referring to.

Comment: I am saying that you should not have separate tables. Have a single table for all of it. I am sorry, if I am not getting the full picture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, regardless. That would solve the hierarchy problem, but wouldn't indicate which tables should be linked to.